# header shifting to left on scrolling the page down (when using affix in bootstrap in html )

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using affix in bootstrap to fix the header at the top when I scroll the page down. But when I do this, the header shifts to left. I want that this shifting to left should not occur.

Can someone please help.

I want that when I scroll down, the header alignment should not shift.

Below is my code ( after incorporating the changes suggested by manish):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<style>
  .affix {
                position: fixed;
      top: 0;
      width: 100%;
      z-index: 9999 !important;
      background-color: #fff;
      align-content: flex-end;


        left: 0;
        right: 0;
        display: table;
        margin: 0 auto;
        max-width: calc(1170px); //container width - 30px padding
        word-wrap: break-word;


  }

  .lin
    {

    color:windowtext;
    font-size:8.0pt;
    font-style:normal;
    text-decoration:none;
    font-family:Arial, sans-serif;
    text-align:left;
    vertical-align:bottom;
    /*width:20px;*/
    }

  .sol
    {

    color:windowtext;
    font-size:8.0pt;
    font-style:normal;
    text-decoration:none;
    font-family:Arial, sans-serif;
    text-align:left;
    vertical-align:bottom;
    /*width:20px;*/
    }

</style>

</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <h2>sssssssssdhhdhdhd dddddd for Hello sssssssdd</h2>

  <table class="table table-striped" width:1170px>

    <thead data-spy="affix" data-offset-top="10">

      <tr>      
      <th>Current Rel<br/>
        Arssstecture<br/>
        fitrtyr<br/>
        of OS
        </th>

        <th>aupporz <br/>
            asdins</th>

        <th>aussorz <br/>
            znds</th>

        <th><br/>
        a34<br/>
        (IAas)<br/>
        31
        </th>

        <th>Pinux<br/>
        a86_64<br/>
        63
        </th>

        <th><br/>
        <br/>
        xCC
        </th>

         <th><br/>
        <br/>
        abc 
        </th>

        <th><br/>
        sd51<br/>
        (sdanium)<br/>
        64
        </th>

        <th>
        sdhetr<br/><br/>
        32
        </th>

        <th>
        sdhetr<br/><br/>
        64
        </th>

        <th>
        pun/aassssu<br/>
        aaaaa<br/>
        64<br/>
        </th>

        <th>
        pun<br/>
        a86_64<br/>
        14<br/>
        </th>

        <th>
        cIX<br/>
        weakiPC<br/>
        63<br/>
        </th>

        <th>
        aP<br/>
        aA <br/>
        aISC<br/>
        34<br/>
        </th>

        <th>
        pandows<br/>
        a16<br/>
        31<br/>
        </th>
      </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody style="font-size:11px">
      <tr>
      <td>asd 16.6 (9)</td>
        <td >10/24/1800</td>
        <td >3/31/1900</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td class = "lin">asdf5, asdf6, ssss 10, ssss 11</td>
        <td ></td>
         <td ></td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td class = "sol">sdhetr 10 (34 dftOnly)</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td class = "sol">sd oiu, sdhetr 2008, Vist enterenter, winwins 7 (32/64)   
</td>
      </tr>
       <tr>
      <td>asd 16.6 (9)</td>
        <td >10/24/1800</td>
        <td >3/31/1900</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td class = "lin">asdf5, asdf6, ssss 10, ssss 11</td>
        <td ></td>
         <td ></td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td class = "sol">sdhetr 10 (34 dftOnly)</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td class = "sol">sd oiu, sdhetr 2008, Vist enterenter, winwins 7 (32/64)   
</td>
      </tr>
       <tr>
      <td>asd 16.6 (9)</td>
        <td >10/24/1800</td>
        <td >3/31/1900</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td class = "lin">asdf5, asdf6, ssss 10, ssss 11</td>
        <td ></td>
         <td ></td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td class = "sol">sdhetr 10 (34 dftOnly)</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td class = "sol">sd oiu, sdhetr 2008, Vist enterenter, winwins 7 (32/64)   
</td>
      </tr>
       <tr>
      <td>asd 16.6 (9)</td>
        <td >10/24/1800</td>
        <td >3/31/1900</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td class = "lin">asdf5, asdf6, ssss 10, ssss 11</td>
        <td ></td>
         <td ></td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td class = "sol">sdhetr 10 (34 dftOnly)</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td class = "sol">sd oiu, sdhetr 2008, Vist enterenter, winwins 7 (32/64)   
</td>
      </tr>
       <tr>
      <td>asd 16.6 (9)</td>
        <td >10/24/1800</td>
        <td >3/31/1900</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td class = "lin">asdf5, asdf6, ssss 10, ssss 11</td>
        <td ></td>
         <td ></td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td class = "sol">sdhetr 10 (34 dftOnly)</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td class = "sol">sd oiu, sdhetr 2008, Vist enterenter, winwins 7 (32/64)   
</td>
      </tr>
       <tr>
      <td>asd 16.6 (9)</td>
        <td >10/24/1800</td>
        <td >3/31/1900</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td class = "lin">asdf5, asdf6, ssss 10, ssss 11</td>
        <td ></td>
         <td ></td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td class = "sol">sdhetr 10 (34 dftOnly)</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td class = "sol">sd oiu, sdhetr 2008, Vist enterenter, winwins 7 (32/64)   
</td>
      </tr>
       <tr>
      <td>asd 16.6 (9)</td>
        <td >10/24/1800</td>
        <td >3/31/1900</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td class = "lin">asdf5, asdf6, ssss 10, ssss 11</td>
        <td ></td>
         <td ></td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td class = "sol">sdhetr 10 (34 dftOnly)</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td class = "sol">sd oiu, sdhetr 2008, Vist enterenter, winwins 7 (32/64)   
</td>
      </tr>
       <tr>
      <td>asd 16.6 (9)</td>
        <td >10/24/1800</td>
        <td >3/31/1900</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td class = "lin">asdf5, asdf6, ssss 10, ssss 11</td>
        <td ></td>
         <td ></td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td class = "sol">sdhetr 10 (34 dftOnly)</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td class = "sol">sd oiu, sdhetr 2008, Vist enterenter, winwins 7 (32/64)   
</td>
      </tr>
       <tr>
      <td>asd 16.6 (9)</td>
        <td >10/24/1800</td>
        <td >3/31/1900</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td class = "lin">asdf5, asdf6, ssss 10, ssss 11</td>
        <td ></td>
         <td ></td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td class = "sol">sdhetr 10 (34 dftOnly)</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td class = "sol">sd oiu, sdhetr 2008, Vist enterenter, winwins 7 (32/64)   
</td>
      </tr>
       <tr>
      <td>asd 16.6 (9)</td>
        <td >10/24/1800</td>
        <td >3/31/1900</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td class = "lin">asdf5, asdf6, ssss 10, ssss 11</td>
        <td ></td>
         <td ></td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td class = "sol">sdhetr 10 (34 dftOnly)</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td class = "sol">sd oiu, sdhetr 2008, Vist enterenter, winwins 7 (32/64)   
</td>
      </tr>
       <tr>
      <td>asd 16.6 (9)</td>
        <td >10/24/1800</td>
        <td >3/31/1900</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td class = "lin">asdf5, asdf6, ssss 10, ssss 11</td>
        <td ></td>
         <td ></td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td class = "sol">sdhetr 10 (34 dftOnly)</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td class = "sol">sd oiu, sdhetr 2008, Vist enterenter, winwins 7 (32/64)   
</td>
      </tr>
       <tr>
      <td>asd 16.6 (9)</td>
        <td >10/24/1800</td>
        <td >3/31/1900</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td class = "lin">asdf5, asdf6, ssss 10, ssss 11</td>
        <td ></td>
         <td ></td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td class = "sol">sdhetr 10 (34 dftOnly)</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td class = "sol">sd oiu, sdhetr 2008, Vist enterenter, winwins 7 (32/64)   
</td>
      </tr>
       <tr>
      <td>asd 16.6 (9)</td>
        <td >10/24/1800</td>
        <td >3/31/1900</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td class = "lin">asdf5, asdf6, ssss 10, ssss 11</td>
        <td ></td>
         <td ></td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td class = "sol">sdhetr 10 (34 dftOnly)</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td class = "sol">sd oiu, sdhetr 2008, Vist enterenter, winwins 7 (32/64)   
</td>
      </tr>
       <tr>
      <td>asd 16.6 (9)</td>
        <td >10/24/1800</td>
        <td >3/31/1900</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td class = "lin">asdf5, asdf6, ssss 10, ssss 11</td>
        <td ></td>
         <td ></td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td class = "sol">sdhetr 10 (34 dftOnly)</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td class = "sol">sd oiu, sdhetr 2008, Vist enterenter, winwins 7 (32/64)   
</td>
      </tr>
       <tr>
      <td>asd 16.6 (9)</td>
        <td >10/24/1800</td>
        <td >3/31/1900</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td class = "lin">asdf5, asdf6, ssss 10, ssss 11</td>
        <td ></td>
         <td ></td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td class = "sol">sdhetr 10 (34 dftOnly)</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td class = "sol">sd oiu, sdhetr 2008, Vist enterenter, winwins 7 (32/64)   
</td>
      </tr>
       <tr>
      <td>asd 16.6 (9)</td>
        <td >10/24/1800</td>
        <td >3/31/1900</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td class = "lin">asdf5, asdf6, ssss 10, ssss 11</td>
        <td ></td>
         <td ></td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td class = "sol">sdhetr 10 (34 dftOnly)</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td class = "sol">sd oiu, sdhetr 2008, Vist enterenter, winwins 7 (32/64)   
</td>
      </tr>
       <tr>
      <td>asd 16.6 (9)</td>
        <td >10/24/1800</td>
        <td >3/31/1900</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td class = "lin">asdf5, asdf6, ssss 10, ssss 11</td>
        <td ></td>
         <td ></td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td class = "sol">sdhetr 10 (34 dftOnly)</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td class = "sol">sd oiu, sdhetr 2008, Vist enterenter, winwins 7 (32/64)   
</td>
      </tr>
       <tr>
      <td>asd 16.6 (9)</td>
        <td >10/24/1800</td>
        <td >3/31/1900</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td class = "lin">asdf5, asdf6, ssss 10, ssss 11</td>
        <td ></td>
         <td ></td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td class = "sol">sdhetr 10 (34 dftOnly)</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td class = "sol">sd oiu, sdhetr 2008, Vist enterenter, winwins 7 (32/64)   
</td>
      </tr>
       <tr>
      <td>asd 16.6 (9)</td>
        <td >10/24/1800</td>
        <td >3/31/1900</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td class = "lin">asdf5, asdf6, ssss 10, ssss 11</td>
        <td ></td>
         <td ></td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td class = "sol">sdhetr 10 (34 dftOnly)</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td class = "sol">sd oiu, sdhetr 2008, Vist enterenter, winwins 7 (32/64)   
</td>
      </tr>
       <tr>
      <td>asd 16.6 (9)</td>
        <td >10/24/1800</td>
        <td >3/31/1900</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td class = "lin">asdf5, asdf6, ssss 10, ssss 11</td>
        <td ></td>
         <td ></td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td class = "sol">sdhetr 10 (34 dftOnly)</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td class = "sol">sd oiu, sdhetr 2008, Vist enterenter, winwins 7 (32/64)   
</td>
      </tr>
       <tr>
      <td>asd 16.6 (9)</td>
        <td >10/24/1800</td>
        <td >3/31/1900</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td class = "lin">asdf5, asdf6, ssss 10, ssss 11</td>
        <td ></td>
         <td ></td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td class = "sol">sdhetr 10 (34 dftOnly)</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td class = "sol">sd oiu, sdhetr 2008, Vist enterenter, winwins 7 (32/64)   
</td>
      </tr>
       <tr>
      <td>asd 16.6 (9)</td>
        <td >10/24/1800</td>
        <td >3/31/1900</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td class = "lin">asdf5, asdf6, ssss 10, ssss 11</td>
        <td ></td>
         <td ></td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td class = "sol">sdhetr 10 (34 dftOnly)</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td class = "sol">sd oiu, sdhetr 2008, Vist enterenter, winwins 7 (32/64)   
</td>
      </tr>
       <tr>
      <td>asd 16.6 (9)</td>
        <td >10/24/1800</td>
        <td >3/31/1900</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td class = "lin">asdf5, asdf6, ssss 10, ssss 11</td>
        <td ></td>
         <td ></td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td class = "sol">sdhetr 10 (34 dftOnly)</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td class = "sol">sd oiu, sdhetr 2008, Vist enterenter, winwins 7 (32/64)   
</td>
      </tr>
       <tr>
      <td>asd 16.6 (9)</td>
        <td >10/24/1800</td>
        <td >3/31/1900</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td class = "lin">asdf5, asdf6, ssss 10, ssss 11</td>
        <td ></td>
         <td ></td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td class = "sol">sdhetr 10 (34 dftOnly)</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td class = "sol">sd oiu, sdhetr 2008, Vist enterenter, winwins 7 (32/64)   
</td>
      </tr>
       <tr>
      <td>asd 16.6 (9)</td>
        <td >10/24/1800</td>
        <td >3/31/1900</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td class = "lin">asdf5, asdf6, ssss 10, ssss 11</td>
        <td ></td>
         <td ></td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td class = "sol">sdhetr 10 (34 dftOnly)</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td class = "sol">sd oiu, sdhetr 2008, Vist enterenter, winwins 7 (32/64)   
</td>
      </tr>
       <tr>
      <td>asd 16.6 (9)</td>
        <td >10/24/1800</td>
        <td >3/31/1900</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td class = "lin">asdf5, asdf6, ssss 10, ssss 11</td>
        <td ></td>
         <td ></td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td class = "sol">sdhetr 10 (34 dftOnly)</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td class = "sol">sd oiu, sdhetr 2008, Vist enterenter, winwins 7 (32/64)   
</td>
      </tr>
       <tr>
      <td>asd 16.6 (9)</td>
        <td >10/24/1800</td>
        <td >3/31/1900</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td class = "lin">asdf5, asdf6, ssss 10, ssss 11</td>
        <td ></td>
         <td ></td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td class = "sol">sdhetr 10 (34 dftOnly)</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td >NA</td>
        <td class = "sol">sd oiu, sdhetr 2008, Vist enterenter, winwins 7 (32/64)   
</td>
      </tr>




    </tbody>
    </table>
</div>



</body>

</html>
```

Comment: No one will care to read your question if u just dump your codes like this.

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<style>
  body {
  background-color: #bdc3c7;
}

.table-fixed {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #f3f3f3;
}
.table-fixed tbody {
  height: 200px;
  overflow-y: auto;
  width: 100%;
}
.table-fixed thead, .table-fixed tbody, .table-fixed tr, .table-fixed td, .table-fixed th {
  display: block;
}
.table-fixed tbody td {
  float: left;
}
.table-fixed thead tr th {
  float: left;
  background-color: #f39c12;
  border-color: #e67e22;
}


</style>

</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <table class="table table-fixed">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th class="col-xs-3">First Name</th>
        <th class="col-xs-3">Last Name</th>
        <th class="col-xs-6">E-mail</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td class="col-xs-3">John</td>
        <td class="col-xs-3">Doe</td>
        <td class="col-xs-6">johndoe@email.com</td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td class="col-xs-3">John</td>
        <td class="col-xs-3">Doe</td>
        <td class="col-xs-6">johndoe@email.com</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="col-xs-3">John</td>
        <td class="col-xs-3">Doe</td>
        <td class="col-xs-6">johndoe@email.com</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="col-xs-3">John</td>
        <td class="col-xs-3">Doe</td>
        <td class="col-xs-6">johndoe@email.com</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="col-xs-3">John</td>
        <td class="col-xs-3">Doe</td>
        <td class="col-xs-6">johndoe@email.com</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="col-xs-3">John</td>
        <td class="col-xs-3">Doe</td>
        <td class="col-xs-6">johndoe@email.com</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="col-xs-3">John</td>
        <td class="col-xs-3">Doe</td>
        <td class="col-xs-6">johndoe@email.com</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="col-xs-3">John</td>
        <td class="col-xs-3">Doe</td>
        <td class="col-xs-6">johndoe@email.com</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="col-xs-3">John</td>
        <td class="col-xs-3">Doe</td>
        <td class="col-xs-6">johndoe@email.com</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="col-xs-3">John</td>
        <td class="col-xs-3">Doe</td>
        <td class="col-xs-6">johndoe@email.com</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="col-xs-3">John</td>
        <td class="col-xs-3">Doe</td>
        <td class="col-xs-6">johndoe@email.com</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="col-xs-3">John</td>
        <td class="col-xs-3">Doe</td>
        <td class="col-xs-6">johndoe@email.com</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="col-xs-3">John</td>
        <td class="col-xs-3">Doe</td>
        <td class="col-xs-6">johndoe@email.com</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="col-xs-3">John</td>
        <td class="col-xs-3">Doe</td>
        <td class="col-xs-6">johndoe@email.com</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="col-xs-3">John</td>
        <td class="col-xs-3">Doe</td>
        <td class="col-xs-6">johndoe@email.com</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="col-xs-3">John</td>
        <td class="col-xs-3">Doe</td>
        <td class="col-xs-6">johndoe@email.com</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="col-xs-3">John</td>
        <td class="col-xs-3">Doe</td>
        <td class="col-xs-6">johndoe@email.com</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="col-xs-3">John</td>
        <td class="col-xs-3">Doe</td>
        <td class="col-xs-6">johndoe@email.com</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="col-xs-3">John</td>
        <td class="col-xs-3">Doe</td>
        <td class="col-xs-6">johndoe@email.com</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="col-xs-3">John</td>
        <td class="col-xs-3">Doe</td>
        <td class="col-xs-6">johndoe@email.com</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>



</body>

</html>
```